# iOS11 SearchController - SearchBar removal from navigationItem leaves broken UI

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, uisearchcontroller

When i remove the searchController from navigationItem by setting 'nil'. Empty space is left behind where it used to be instead of collapsing.

Tried calling,

```
searchController.dismiss()
navigationController.navigationItem.searchController.dismiss()
navigationItem.searchController.dismiss()
searchController.isActive = false
```

Nothing worked.

---

P.S - Using simulator

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should layout subviews after removing search controller. The trick is *which superview*'s subview you have to layout: since `navigationItem` is part of navigation stack, so you should call `layoutSubviews()` onto current `navigationController`:

```
navigationItem.searchController = nil
navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

According to Apple Documentation you shouldn't call `layoutSubviews()` directly.

Comment: This is working fine, to add it back just `navigationItem.searchController = yourSearchControllerObject`

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. It do notice my tableview/search content shifts up to the correct position, but the size of the navigation bar is still too large.

Comment: saved my day! i was wrapping my head around this issue for hours. This is the only thing that worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

If you are setting the below, then remove this line

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = search
```

Comment: The empty space still persists and if the searchbar is active it disappears along with the navigationbar.

Comment: That answer along with setting it to nil afterwards worked. Thanks. :D

Comment: I had an issue where if I used the code above and I segued using the navController, no matter what I did the header for the nav would appear for the childVC.  To solve that I used this line first.

navigationItem.searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

I hope this solves and weird issues with VC's segueing you might get from the actions above.

Comment: doing this seemed to work but i noticed the search bar still present in the view hierarchy. @SergeyGamayunov answer worked for me